# #1 of the Memebus™

Tags: rebus, knowledge

[image: RebusPart1]
[image: RebusPart2]
[image: RebusPart3]
[image: RebusPart4]
[image: RebusPart5]

What phrase does this rebus represent?
(Apologies in advance for MSPaint skills)

Comment: Horses, neighs, toilets, Johns, MSPaint... I see what you did there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My guess is:

> [And his name is John Cena...](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/unexpected-john-cena-and-his-name-is-john-cena)

First line:

> It's Andy Bernard from The Office == Andy's

Second line:

> A horse and a speaker (sound) symbol == the sound a horse makes == Neigh

Third line:

> A woman without a ring (i.e. not married) == Miss

Fourth line:

> A toilet, also sometimes called a john == John

Fifth line:

> Lucina (from Fire Emblem) minus Lou (Ferrigno) == "Cina" == Cena

All together:

> Andy's Neigh Miss John Cina == And his name is John Cena...

Comment: Beat me to it. :P

Comment: 